# navigation menu indicating where user is

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu on my page that has 4 different areas a person can navigate to:

```
Home
About
Contact
Privacy
```

I would like when a user clicks on one of these links, I get an indicator of it in the menu.  so if user clicks About, he will see

```
Home
-->About
Contact
Privacy
```

I am using an ol with jquery to fill another section of the page with the data related to the clicked subject.

my html:

```
 <div class='home'><a href='#' class='navigate' id='home'><ol>Home</ol></a></div>
 <div class='about'><a href='#' class='navigate' id='about'><ol>About</ol></a></div>
 <div class='contact'><a href='#' class='navigate' id='contact'><ol>Contact</ol></a></div>
 <div class='privacy'><a href='#' class='navigate' id='privacy'><ol>Privacy</ol></a></div>
```

The navigate class:

```
 $('.navigate').click (function() {

 //Show a animiated gif
 $('#loading').show();

 //id of module        
    var module = $(this).attr('id');

 //get id of modules a href id
            var childId = $("."+module).children("a").attr("id");

 //add --> to the div
            $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).html("-->"+childId);

 //post to navigate.php and do stuff.
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "navigate.php",
                   data: "module="+module,
                   success: function(result)
                   {
                            $('#mainBody').html(result);
                            $('#loading').hide();
                   }
                    })
    })      
    });
```

with this attempt, I am able to get a "-->" in the correct ol, however, i cant remove the others and lose the href links.  obviously, i am going to replace the --> with a cool little arrow image when i figure this out.

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q4H2k/1/

Comment: An ordered list <ol> with content outside of a list item <li> is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

**JS**

```
$('.navigate').removeClass('active'); // Remove active from all elements in the menu
$(this).addClass('active'); // Add active class to the element being clicked
```

**CSS**

```
.active:before {
   content: "---> "; // Apply styling for the active element here
}
```

Imo, it is much "cleaner" to indicate active menu-element by giving it a class. This way you can simply remove the class without having to mess with inner-html. You also have much more control of how you want the styling. If you want something other than `--->` you can style a special color, bullet or something else. Look at how other sites does it.

Comment: So my css is:content: url(pointer.png);
how can i change the size of that image?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @OptimusCrime's code, you can simply do:

```
// Match all navigate
$('.navigate').click(function () {
  // Delete all the arrows
  $("ol .current").remove();
  // Add the arrow only in the relevant one
  $(this).find("ol").prepend("<span class = 'current'>--></span>");
  });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4H2k/6/). It is more retro-compatible and I find it easier.

Furthermore, I'd change the html to

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a data-link = "home">
        Home
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-link = "about">
        About
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Since it's semantic and more SEO-friendly than what you have now currently. Then the jquery is even simpler:

```
// Match all navigate
$('nav a').click(function () {
  // Delete all the arrows
  $("nav .current").remove();
  // Add the arrow only in the relevant one
  $(this).prepend("<span class = 'current'>--></span>");
  });
```